# user_data script not being executed at boot time but it works when executed manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a simple powershell script that I would like to be executed at boot time so that EC2 instance registers with an ECS cluster:

**user_data.ps1**

```
Import-Module ECSTools
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE", $TRUE, "Machine")
Initialize-ECSAgent -Cluster "my-dev-cluster" -EnableTaskIAMRole -EnableTaskENI
```

After the instance boots, I do not see it registered with my ECS cluster. However, if I execute the script manually following those steps it works:

- go to EC2 and then select the instance and then Actions -> Instance Settings -> Edit User data
- then copy the user data script
- connect to the instance using Session Manager
- paste and execute the user-data script

I see the EC2 registered with the ECS cluster.

Can somebody please explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to encapsulate my powershell script withing a `</powershell>` tags like so:

```
<powershell>
Import-Module ECSTools
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE", $TRUE, "Machine")
Initialize-ECSAgent -Cluster "my-dev-cluster" -EnableTaskIAMRole -EnableTaskENI
</powershell>
```

After that  my powershell script user_data was executing successfully and my ECS instance was registered with the cluster fine